# What is the difference between ALL & DEBUG trace levels in LOG4NET

Tags: log4net

I would like to know why do we have All and Debug trace levels in log4net? they seems to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ALL` really means all levels and `DEBUG` means only Debug or higher. Often this does not make a difference because Debug is the lowest level that the ILog interface exposes. Log4net does however have a lot more log levels and if you build a wrapper that supports additional levels you may prefer to use `ALL` to make sure you really get all messages.

**EDIT:**

DEBUG or higher means the following levels if you are using only standard levels: DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

Assuming you would in addition use a VERBOSE level then you would only see it in your log file if you use ALL or VERBOSE in the configuration. Using DEBUG would filter all VERBOSE messages. Log4net knows the following levels that are lower then DEBUG: FINE, TRACE, FINER, VERBOSE, FINEST.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Stefan.
Yes, but again even if we use DEBUG also, we will get the additional levels from our wrapper. Is it just to give clear idea to the developer what level he is logging ?

Comment: what levels are you seeing that you do not expect? see also my updated answer

Comment: Scorp, you can mark Stefan's response as Answer if it's what you need. It would help making StackOverflow more clean :)